# All virtual hosts redirected to one

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost

So I have 2 Virtual hosts on my server 192.168.1.90
Configured as follows :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/webmaster/www/PP
ServerName www.pinpin123.com
ServerAlias pinpin123.com

# Other directives here
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName discuss.pinpin123.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001/
</VirtualHost>
```

***Are in separate files in /ete/apache2/sites-available linked to in sites-enabled**

The problem is when a client visits pinpin123.com they get redirected to discuss.pinpin123.com

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are trying to proxy to a different port on the same server? That's not really necessary. All you need is to have `DocumentRoot` directives for the two virtual hosts pointing to the two (different) locations where the files for the two (different) sites are stored.

Comment: A instance of Liquid Feedback is running on port 8001, need to proxy it there.

Comment: Your site is down. After you get your site back up, post the _rest_ of your Apache configuration.

Comment: its a local server, not open to internet

Answer (score -1):

You can many solution for solve it:

- using iptables
- using /etc/hosts
- using virtualhost according to ip (defining alias ethernet eth:1 eth:2 )

Comment: what should i  do,